# Error deploying or retrieving source by package.xml

Tags: deployment, package, package.xml, retrieve

When I attempted to retrieve source by package.xml, I got this error:

```
Error deploying or retrieving source: The file or directory that you tried to deploy or retrieve isn't in a package 
directory that's specified in your sfdx-project.json file. 
Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. 
For details about sfdx-project.json, see: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm
```

This is my sfdx-project.json

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "StudentManagementSystem",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "55.0"
}
```

This is my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please the command you used to retrieve the data or how you did it with VSCoode? Side-note: I suggest keep consistent the API version on package XML and project JSON file.

Comment: @JefersonChaves I retrieve source by right click and select SFDX: Retrieve this source from org in package.xml file. Is it correct?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your folder structure or add in here?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Cannot comment XML file by default in VScode (Salesforce Extension Pack)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310526/cannot-comment-xml-file-by-default-in-vscode-salesforce-extension-pack) This looks like the same condition where you have an xml setting to override the type association for the manifest file.
You should be getting the manifest specific commands like `SFDX:Deploy Source in Manifest to Org`. The fact you are getting the standard deploy/retrieve commands on a manifest files indicates the manifest isn't being recognized by the SF VSCode extensions.